# Cannot deploy to Azure Website using VSO Agent

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to deploy several websites to Azure with the new Release-feature and a on-prem hosted VSO Agent.

It does deploy to one website in Azure but the others are failing and I can't see any difference in their setup: Same subscription, same properties even hosted on same Azure VM...

The error I'm getting is in the vso-log:

```
06:59:15.489161 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = Looking for Azure PowerShell module at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Azure.psd1)
06:59:16.467323 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = AzurePSCmdletsVersion= 1.0.4)
06:59:16.485822 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = Get-ServiceEndpoint -Name xxxxxxxx-c8b1-4f15-b59d-0d453e7bd3c5 -Context Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Worker.Common.TaskContext)
06:59:17.029746 Process logging event with task handler.
06:59:17.029746 BaseLogger.LogStatus(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, scope.TimelineRecordId = 52fb11d3-73c4-4ac8-a975-88b832a486e8, record.Name = )
06:59:17.029746 Process logging event with task handler.
06:59:17.029746 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = subscription= BizSpark)
06:59:17.049540 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = Get-X509Certificate -CredentialsXml <xml>)
06:59:17.139173 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = azureSubscriptionId= xxxxxxxx-d906-4f32-9eda-a51708827ea3)
06:59:17.139173 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = azureSubscriptionName= BizSpark)
06:59:17.139173 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = azureServiceEndpoint= https://management.core.windows.net/)
06:59:17.159043 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName BizSpark -SubscriptionId xxxxxxxx-d906-4f32-9eda-a51708827ea3 -Certificate <cert> -Environment AzureCloud)
06:59:17.201634 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId xxxxxx-d906-4f32-9eda-a51708827ea3)
06:59:17.268742 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = ConnectedServiceName= 28ab7968-c8b1-4f15-b59d-0d453e7bd3c5)
06:59:17.268742 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = WebSiteName= my-azure-website)
06:59:17.268742 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = Package= d:\b\5581ca786\Complete Build\dotNetComponents\Reporting\obj\Release\Package\WebDeploy.zip)
06:59:17.268742 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = Slot= )
06:59:17.268742 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = AdditionalArguments= )
06:59:17.268742 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = packageFile= Find-Files -SearchPattern d:\b\5581ca786\Complete Build\dotNetComponents\Reporting\obj\Release\Package\WebDeploy.zip)
06:59:17.268742 FindFiles.FindMatchingFiles(rootFolder = , matchPattern = d:\b\5581ca786\Complete Build\dotNetComponents\Reporting\obj\Release\Package\WebDeploy.zip, includeFiles = True, includeFolders = False
06:59:17.268742 FindFiles.GetMatchingItems(includePatterns.Count = 1, excludePatterns.Count = 0, includeFiles = True, includeFolders = False
06:59:17.268742 FindFiles.GetMatchingItems - Found: d:\b\5581ca786\Complete Build\dotNetComponents\Reporting\obj\Release\Package\WebDeploy.zip
06:59:17.279765 FindFiles.FindMatchingFiles - Found 1 matches
06:59:17.279765 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = packageFile= d:\b\5581ca786\Complete Build\dotNetComponents\Reporting\obj\Release\Package\WebDeploy.zip)
06:59:17.279765 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = Get-AzureWebSite -Name my-azure-website -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable azureWebSiteError -Slot production)
06:59:18.311104 Process logging event with task handler.
06:59:18.311104 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = ##[warning]System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException: There is no Runspace available to run scripts in this thread. You can provide one in the DefaultRunspace property of the System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace type. The script block you attempted to invoke was: $CurrentSession.ignoreCert)
06:59:18.311104 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = ##[warning]   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult))
06:59:18.311104 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = ##[warning]   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar))
06:59:18.311104 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = ##[warning]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---)
06:59:18.328418 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = ##[warning]   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult))
06:59:18.328418 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = ##[warning]   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar))
06:59:18.328418 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = ##[warning]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---)
06:59:18.328418 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = ##[warning]   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task))
06:59:18.328418 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = ##[warning]   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task))
06:59:18.328418 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = ##[warning]   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites.WebSpaceOperationsExtensions.List(IWebSpaceOperations operations))
06:59:18.328418 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = ##[warning]   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Websites.Services.WebSitesManagementExtensionMethods.GetFromAzure(IWebSiteManagementClient client, String website))
06:59:18.328418 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = ##[warning]   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Websites.WebsitesClient.GetWebsite(String name))
06:59:18.328418 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = ##[warning]   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.GetAzureWebsiteCommand.<GetByName>b__0())
06:59:18.328418 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = ##[warning]   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.GetAzureWebsiteCommand.Do(Action call))
06:59:18.328418 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = ##[warning]   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord())
06:59:18.347881 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = New-AzureWebSite -Name my-azure-website -Location North Europe -Slot production)
06:59:19.235932 Process logging event with task handler.
06:59:19.235932 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 1ca0ac28-56bc-4bcb-8081-2b97efa19f68, message = ##[error]An error occurred while sending the request.)
```

**UPDATE:**

My release "script" looks like this:
[image]

Nothing fancy in my mind, but only the first Website deploys successfully

I have one build that compiles one solution with these four websites in as web deployment packages

**UPDATE 2 - It works (sort of)**

Ok, this is maybe not "as designed", but it works:

- I have four websites A, B, C and D.
- Deploy A, B, C and D => A succeeds, B, C and D fails
- Deploy B, A, C and D => A and B succeeds, C and D fails
- Deploy C, B, A and D => A, B and C succeeds, D fails
- Deploy D, C, B and A => A, B, C and D succeeds!!!

It looks to me that the deployment script is doing some kind of magic configuration to only the first website?!?

I really hope MS finds this bug and in the meanwhile this might help others in the same situation

Comment: Are you trying to deploy multiple websites in the same build? Can you provide some additional details about the web apps and their configuration.

Comment: Can you tell me what version of the Azure PowerShell cmdlets you have installed?

Comment: Are you trying to create new Azure Websites during the deployment? And is there any firewall software installed on the agent?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson: AzureWebPowerShellDeployment is version 1.0.23

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I've already created and configured the websites in the Azure Portal. The Agent is running on a standard Azure VM (Win10 image), so I don't believe that it is a firewall issue...

Comment: @CasperJensen According to the logs, the "Get-AzureWebsite" command failed and the script was trying to create a new website. Can you run "Get-AzureWebsite" command from the Agent to see if it can be succeed? Reference for this command: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495127.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think The issue is in the FTP Uploader extension you have installed. I have a modified version of this in my environment as it causes any web deploy actions after it in the chain of tasks to fail.

Re-ordering is masking the underlying issue but lets me get the release successfully into all the websites.